# How do I build a LIKE query with DbCommand/Query Builder?

Tags: plugin-development, database, mysql

I'm trying to construct a fairly simple LIKE query using the [Query Builder](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/database#query-builder), and I'm struggling. Here's the SQL that I want:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `craft_somecustomtable` WHERE ((`somecolumn` LIKE '%foo%') OR (`somecolumn` LIKE '%bar%'))
```

I've ran the above query in Sequel, with results.

For the Query Builder, here's what I've got so far:

```
$query = craft()->db->createCommand();
$query->select('id');
$query->from('somecustomtable');
$query->orWhere(array(
    'somecolumn' => 'LIKE %foo%',
));
$query->orWhere(array(
    'somecolumn' => 'LIKE %bar%',
));
```

This produces the following query, which obviously doesn't work as intended:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `craft_somecustomtable` WHERE ((`somecolumn`='LIKE %foo%') OR (`somecolumn`='LIKE %bar%'))
```

I've also tried adding the `LIKE` directive like this:

```
$query->orWhere(array(
    'somecolumn LIKE' => '%bar%',
));
```

This produces an error, however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just before posting the question, I had the good mind to read the [Yii CDbCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand) docs again, and I figured this out myself:

```
$query->orWhere(array(
    'like',
    'somecolumn',
    '%foo%'
));
```